# Bound error in Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display list of vehicles from db in webgrid .but when i run code there comes error in view.chstml that "datasource must be bound" though i used correct model name and db name .

Model : Vehicles

```
   public List<Vehicles> Listvehicle(string uid)
    {

        List<Vehicles> svehicle;

         using (var session = MvcApplication.Store.OpenSession())
         {

        svehicle = (from vehc in session.Query<Vehicles>() where vehc.userid == uid select vehc).ToList();

         }
         return svehicle;

    }
```

Controller

```
      [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Listvehilce(string uid)
    {
        string userName = "ksundas7@gmail.com";

        Register reg = new Register();
        string userId = reg.userid(userName);
        Vehicles vehcl = new Vehicles();
        List<Vehicles> vehclist = vehcl.Listvehicle(userId);
        vehclist.ToList();
       // List<Vehicles> svehicle = WebGrid.Listvehicle(userId);

        return View();
    }
```

View

```
     @model  IEnumerable<MvcMembership.Models.Vehicles>

     @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Listvehicle";
   }
   <h2>Listvehilce</h2>
  @{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 3,                selectionFieldName: "selectedRow");
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 


 <style type="text/css">

    .table { margin: 4px;  width: 500px;  background-color:#FCFCFC;}

    .head { background-color: #C1D4E6; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }

    .webGrid th, .webGrid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }

    .altRow { background-color: #E4E9F5; color: #000; }

    .gridHead a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}

    .description { width:auto}

    .selectRow{background-color: #389DF5}

</style>

 @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid",

            headerStyle: "head",

            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",

            selectedRowStyle: "select",

            columns: grid.Columns(

            grid.Column("vehicleid"),// format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.vehicleid)),

            grid.Column("Type", " Type"),

            grid.Column("Make", "Make"),

            grid.Column("Registration", "Registration"),
            grid.Column("Colour", "Colour"),
            grid.Column("Model", "Model")
     ))
```

Error:
A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

Anyone can tell me please  what is reason of this error.
thanks in advance 
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not return the list in view.here is updated code.

```
 [HttpGet]

 public ActionResult Listvehilce(string uid)
{
    string userName = "ksundas7@gmail.com";

    Register reg = new Register();
    string userId = reg.userid(userName);
    Vehicles vehcl = new Vehicles();
    List<Vehicles> vehclist = vehcl.Listvehicle(userId);
    vehclist.ToList();
   // List<Vehicles> svehicle = WebGrid.Listvehicle(userId);

    return View(svehicle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the model is not null when it is being bound to the webgrid?

Also, you can change this part in the controller:

```
    List<Vehicles> vehclist = vehcl.Listvehicle(userId);
    vehclist.ToList();
```

with this
         IEnumerable vehclist = vehcl.Listvehicle(userId);

List already implements the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: i checked model is not null